# How to pass state to MDBDataTable in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with React. I need to pass an object to React's `<MDBDataTable>` but data is in the state. Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Data has to be passed like this

```
<MDBDataTable className="text-center" striped hover bordered small data={this.state}
```

My state looks like this

```
this.state = {
      column: [
        {
          id: 'id'
        },
        {
          serialNumber: 'sn'
        },
        {
          name: 'yr'
        }
      ],
      rows: null
    };
```

Rows are null by default and they are added with this code

```
this.setState({rows: data.map(u => ({
  id: u.id,
  serialNumber: u.login,
  yearRange: u.firstName
}))});
```

When I `console.log(this.state)` it shows the state as it should be. Both `column` and `rows` are populated with data

Comment: where is your `MDBDataTable` can you provide more info on what your component looks like ?

Comment: that is react's component that I am using for displaying data in a table. You can find more about it [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/datatables/)

Comment: I think you need to set data to MDBDataTable like this: data={this.state.rows}

Comment: I have to give it both, column and rows at the same time

Comment: what is the problem with passing like this `data={this.state}` ? any way your state is an  object

Comment: problem is that data is not displayed when I set it like that. It says ```Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries``` but table is empty. When I inspect element on table there is no data in divs in table.

Comment: can you post more code or try simuating that in codesandbox and provide the link here , so that we can better help you out

Comment: I fixed it. Problem what that it was ```columns``` not ```column```.. damn typo :D
Thx for help guys :)